# How to get user configured at <identity impersonate="true"> in web.config to execute some code with it own privileges (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, impersonation

I'm having access denied errors when trying to create directories, move files etc. So I added (web.config) the impersonate user that have the right privileges to execute that functions.

So, in my web.config I have the current code:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>...</handlers>
      <aspNetCore .../>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" password="password123" userName="DOMAIN\user123" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And in my IIS, the `DefaultAppPool` pool have the `Identity` property set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.
[iis pool configuration identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybf4O.png)

And now I use `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated()` to run my code that create the folders and etc that I talked earlier with the purpose to use the configured user (`DOMAIN\user123`), and not the current `User.Identity` logged into, like `DOMAIN\anyOtherCurrentUser`:

```
WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().AccessToken, () => {
      // create directory, move files, etc
});
```

The problem is when I run this code, calling `WindowsIdentity.Getcurrent()`, The user that I'm getting is the current one set on IIS Configuration `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` and not the configured user in web.config `DOMAIN\user123`. Why this happens? How should I use this user configured in web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply cannot.

Anything under `<system.web>` applies to only ASP.NET 4.x or older, and ASP.NET Core does not honor such.

> Even for ASP.NET 4.x you should grant all permissions based on the application pool identity, not relying on impersonation for your own good.

Comment: So, even if I set ASP.NET Impersonation in IIS "Authentication" page configuration, I'll still not get the user defined there, right? It really needs to be at the Application Pool level?


I say that because I have in the same application pool a lot of Web Forms applications running, and now I developed an application with asp.net core and my supervisor says it's unsafe to change the `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool` user to the domain user I want to make the actions without access denied. (and I'm super newbie at IIS, without help is hard to handle this problem)

Comment: So unfortunately I think I wouldn't can change it

Comment: But should I grant full rights to my folder with Application Pool Identity user?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation

Comment: "my supervisor says it's unsafe to change the IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool user to the domain user"? I will laugh out loud, as so many enterprises all use domain user accounts (service accounts) to host their web apps. Safety is governed in many ways, and limiting to IIS AppPoolIdentity won't give you significantly benefits (and impersonation only gives you more trouble).

Comment: Hi. I managed another way to do it (out of this scope), but thanks for your knowledge to made me think about this subject more open mind.